# Real and imaginary part of $\tan(a+bi)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

When dealing with complex trigonometric functions, it is quite natural to ask how the real/imaginary part of $\tan(a+bi)$ can be expressed using $a$ and $b$.
Of course, since $\tan z$ and $\tanh z$ are tightly linked for complex variables, we could derive the real/imaginary part for hyperbolic tangent from  the corresponding results for $\tanh(a+bi)$ and vice-versa. (We have $\tanh(iz)=i\tanh z$ and $\tan(iz)=i\tanh(z)$.)

I was not able to find this in a few basic sources I looked at. For example, I do not see it in the Wikipedia articles [Trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Trigonometric_functions&oldid=861974547)) and [Hyperbolic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hyperbolic_function&oldid=866654186)). (And [List of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_trigonometric_identities&oldid=866317080)) does not mention much about complex trigonometric functions other than the relation to the exponential function.)

I have at least tried to find what are a results for some specific value of $a$ and $b$. I have tried a few values in WolframAlpha, for example, [tangent of $2+i$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(2%2Bi)), [tangent of $1+2i$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(1%2B2i)), [tangent of $1+i$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(1%2Bi)).
On this site I found this question: [Calculate $\tan(1+i)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477297).

I have tried to calculate this myself, probably my approach is rather cumbersome - I post it below as an answer. I will be grateful for references, different derivations, different expressions for this formula. (And I will also be grateful if I receive some corrections to my approach - but do not treat this primarily as a [solution-verification](/questions/tagged/solution-verification) question, it is intended as a general question.)

Comment: Not objectively better, but some might prefer the derivation using $\tan z=\frac{1}{i}\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{e^{2iz}+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

We want to express $\tan(a+bi)$ in the form
$$\tan(a+bi)=A(a,b)+B(a,b)i,$$
the two functions $A(a,b)$ and $B(a,b)$ are what we are looking for.

We have
\begin{align*}
\tan(a+bi)&=\frac{\sin(a+bi)}{\cos(a+bi)}\\
&\overset{(1)}=\frac{\sin a\cos(bi)+\cos(a)\sin(bi)}{\cos a\cos(bi)-\sin a\sin(bi)}\\
&\overset{(2)}=\frac{\sin a\cosh b+i\cos a\sinh b}{\cos a\cosh b-i\sin a\sinh b}\\
&=\frac{(\cos a\cosh b+i\sin a\sinh b)(\sin a\cosh b+i\cos a\sinh b)}{\cos^2a\cosh^2b+\sin^2a\sinh^2b}\\
&=\frac{\cos a\sin a(\cosh^2b-\sinh^2b)+i(\cos^2a+\sin^2a)\cosh b\sinh b}{\cos^2a\cosh^2b+\sin^2a\sinh^2b}\\
&=\frac{\cos a\sin a+i\cosh b\sinh b}{\cos^2a\cosh^2b+\sin^2a\sinh^2b}
\end{align*}

$(1)$: Using sum angle formulas.
$(2)$: Using $\cos iz=\cosh z$ and $\sinh i = i\sinh z$.

We would like to simplify this further, it seems that double argument formulae might help. In the numerator we can use that $\cos a \sin a = \frac{\sin 2a}2$ and $\cosh b \sinh b = \frac{\sinh2b}2$. For the denominator let us try that from the double angle formulas $\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1=1-2\sin^2x$ and $\cosh2x=\cosh^2x+\sinh^2x=2\cosh^2x-1=2\sinh^2x+1$ we can get that
\begin{align*}
\cos^2x&=\frac{1+\cos2x}2\\
\sin^2x&=\frac{1-\cos2x}2\\
\cosh^2x&=\frac{\cosh2x+1}2\\
\sinh^2x&=\frac{\cosh2x-1}2\\
\end{align*}
Now we have for the denominator $D$:
\begin{align*}
D&=\cos^2a\cosh^2b+\sin^2a\sinh^2b\\
&=\frac{1+\cos2a}2\cdot\frac{\cosh2b+1}2+\frac{1-\cos2a}2\cdot\frac{\cosh2b-1}2\\
&=\frac{1+\cos2a+\cosh2b+\cos2a\cosh2b}4+\frac{1+\cos2a-\cosh2b-\cos2a\cosh2b}4\\
&=\frac{\cos2a+\cosh2b}2
\end{align*}
So altogether we get that
$$\tan(a+bi)=\frac{\cos a\sin a+i\cosh b\sinh b}{\cos^2a\cosh^2b+\sin^2a\sinh^2b} = \frac{\sin2a+i\sinh2b}{\cos2a+\cosh2b}.$$
So for the real and imaginary part we get
\begin{align*}
A(a,b)&=\frac{\sin2a}{\cos2a+\cosh2b}\\
B(a,b)&=\frac{\sinh2b}{\cos2a+\cosh2b}
\end{align*}

Comment: How is the $b$ term in the denominators not hyperbolic?  Denoms should be $\cos 2a+\color{blue}{\cosh 2b}$ if we want the right form for a pure imaginary argument.

Comment: Looks like it was just typos, corrected.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks for the corrections, I should have been more careful. (I have read the answer again after posting it, but I obviously missed a few slip-ups.)

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
$$
\tan z=\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}
$$
Note that $\sin\bar{z}=\overline{\sin z}$ and $\cos\bar{z}=\overline{\cos z}$, so the real part is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}+\frac{\sin\bar{z}}{\cos\bar{z}}\right)=
\frac{\sin(z+\bar{z})}{\cos z\cos\bar{z}}
$$
and similarly the imaginary part is
$$
\frac{1}{2i}\frac{\sin(z-\bar{z})}{\cos z\cos\bar{z}}
$$
If $z=a+bi$, then $z+\bar{z}=2a$ and $z-\bar{z}=2bi$, whereas
$$
\cos z=\cos a\cosh b-i\sin a\sinh b
$$
because $\cos(ib)=\cosh b$ and $\sin(ib)=i\sinh b$. Also
$$
\cos z\cos\bar{z}=\lvert\cos z\rvert^2=
\cos^2a\cosh^2b+\sin^2a\sinh^2b
$$
Therefore
$$
\tan(a+bi)=\frac{\sin a\cos a}{\cos^2a\cosh^2b+\sin^2a\sinh^2b}+
i\frac{\sinh b\cosh b}{\cos^2a\cosh^2b+\sin^2a\sinh^2b}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be quite clever approach. The fact about complex conjugate of $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ probably hold a bit more generally - [Holomorphic functions: is it true that $f(\bar{z})=\overline {f(z)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1257144) However, probably for some simple functions such as $\exp$, $\cos$, $\sin$ this can be derived also directly from the definition (from the expansion into Taylor series).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, the key fact is that the coefficients of the Taylor series are real. Or because $\overline{\exp(\bar{z})}$ is holomorphic as well and $\exp(z)-\overline{\exp(\bar{z})}$ is zero on the real axis.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the compound angle formula, viz. $$\tan(a+bi)=\frac{\tan a+\tan bi}{1-\tan a\tan bi}=\frac{\tan a+i\tanh b}{1-i\tan a\tanh b}=\frac{(\tan a +i\tanh b)(1+i\tan a\tanh b)}{1+\tan^2 a\tanh^2 b}.$$The real part is $\frac{\tan a (1-\tanh^2 b)}{1+\tan^2 a\tanh^2 b}=\frac{\tan a \operatorname{sech}^2 b}{1+\tan^2 a\tanh^2 b}$; the imaginary part is $\frac{\tanh b(1+\tan^2 a)}{1+\tan^2 a\tanh^2 b}=\frac{\tanh b\sec^2 a}{1+\tan^2 a\tanh^2 b}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula

$$\tan( \alpha + \beta) = \frac{\sin 2\alpha + \sin 2 \beta}{\cos 2 \alpha + \cos 2 \beta}$$

(the geometric interpretation: the complex number $e^{i 2 \alpha} + e^{i 2 \beta}$ has argument $\alpha + \beta$ - draw a picture!)

We get
$$\tan(x+ i y) = \frac{\sin 2x + \sin i 2 y}{\cos 2x + \cos i 2 y} = \frac{\sin 2x + i \sinh 2y}{\cos 2x + \cosh 2y}$$